# How do I get Twitter OAuth Access Token / Secret from bot chat?

Tags: node.js, authentication, twitter, oauth, chatbot

I have a twitter app which is just a bot that responds to DMs in Twitter itself and sends requests to the Twitter API based on what the interacting user messages the bot.

Right now I have it configured using my own user's OAuth Key & Secret, but I was wondering what the best way is to get the interacting user's authorization? Would I have to create a server and have the bot DM the link for them to click on that sends the token / secret to my server or is there a better way to do this for an app like this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Use oauth2 flow. Specifically the authorization grant flow.

When user access to twitter using the web, enter some strings in the chat and your bot is activated, an url should be returned to the user in the chat.

User clicks on the link and its redirected(another browser tab) to the oauth2 consent form of twiter, with a message like this: Yaezah Bot want to acccess to the following resources on your twitter account. Do you agree?...

If user accepts, is redirected to a link called: callback url in oauth2 theory. This page should show a simple message like: Authorization successful. The backend of this page is yours, so you can get the authorization code, then exchange it for an access_token. Whit this access_token you don't need your clientid/clientsecret. You could consume  any twitter http api sending this access_token as authorization header.

If you are able to get the access_token, store it and then send a message to the user using your bot notifying that bot is ready.

I think it is almost the same on a mobile.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not accurate, as of today, Twitter only uses OAuth 1.0A for user authentication. However, yes, you do need to implement the server-side Sign-in with Twitter flow in order to obtain the user's token and secret.

Comment: Hi Andy, I think you  are right. But according to this link https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0    and https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token twitter is almost ready to offer a full oauth2 feature to the users & developers

Comment: yes, this is coming soon, correct.